# ColdFusion Administrator: adding data source returns "java.sql.SQLException: General error" error

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to add a data source in ColdFusion Administrator. After I fill out fields and click "Submit" I get this error:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: <connection name>
java.sql.SQLException: General error
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: General error
```

Here is screenshot for more clarity:

[image]

I am not sure what could be the problem. All data appears to be entered correctly.

I have 2 questions:

1. Anybody knows what could cause this error?
2. How can I farther debug this error message? Are there some logs I can look at with more details, like a stack trace or something?

Comment: Which driver did you use when you attempted to add a new datasource?

Comment: Check the cfusion\logs directory

Comment: Yes, logs had stack trace, but it was not very useful. It would still require research trying to understand the problem.

Comment: ( As an aside, this has my vote for one of the most useless error messages ever ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was outdated .jar driver file. My database administrator provided me with new, updated version of .jar driver file and that solved the problem.

Driver in question was InterSystems Caché JDBC driver. I am not sure what versions they were (filename was the same - just CacheDB.jar). However, my "bad" .jar was 704 KB, and my "good" .jar is 2,019 KB.

I am also not sure what version of hotfix I am on, but I doubt it's the latest one at the moment of writing this.

Comment: Which driver in particular? And were you updated to latest CF hotfix?

Comment: InterSystems Caché JDBC driver. I don't know what hotfix I'm on but I don't think it's latest.

Comment: @wha7ever - Please put that info within the answer so it's more visible. Also if you know the specific driver version #'s (good and bad) that'd be helpful for the next guy to run into the same issue. Glad you fixed it!

Comment: If you're not on the latest hotfix and the `.jar` file was the problem, just realize that you're risking another update overwriting that file with a different one. Keep some internal documentation that tracks any manual changes like this.